# Windows 10 laptop unable to detect my USB type-C hub correctly

Tags: windows-10, usb, laptop, drivers, usb-hub

I've got a USB type-C hub and it looks like this:

[image: Image. A photo of a small, standalone, external USB see hub]

I was able to use external monitors on my laptop (laptop A) by connecting them to the HDMI interfaces on the hub. However recently it stopped working.

The strange thing is: I can use the hub properly on another laptop (laptop B), so I compared the items displayed in Device Manager, and I found the cause: the hub is shown as `USB Mass Storage Device` after connected to laptop A, and the driver file is `USBSTOR.SYS`:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Windows device properties dialog titled USB mass storage device. The driver files details show that it is using Windows, system 32 drivers, USB store dot sis]

On laptop B, it is shown as `Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub`, and the driver file is `USBHUB3.SYS`.

[image: Image. A cropped screenshot of the Windows Device Manager. A red arrow is pointed at a device marked Generic Super Speed USB hub]

I tried to manually replace the driver (I found there is a `USBHUB3.SYS` driver file on laptop A, and it is actually the same file as on laptop B), however it gives me error when I do so, and it does not seem to work (the device is shown with a yellow exclamation mark.

*Image 1*
[image: Image. A screenshot of a Windows dialog to update drivers for a device. Standard USB Hubs is highlighted as the device description and the model selected is Generic Super Speed USB Hub. Two other model options are shown. These are Generic USB Hub, and USB Root Hub, USB 3 point O]

*Image 2*
[image: Image. A screenshot of a Windows dialog box titled Update Drivers - Generic Super Speed USB hub. A message indicating Windows encountered a problem installing the drivers for the device is shown. Additionally, there is a warning that the device currently isn't working properly because Windows could not load the required drivers for the device, with a code 31]

*Image 3*
[image: Image. A cropped screenshot of the Windows Device Manager. A red arrow is pointing at a device titled Generic Super Speed USB hub. There is a yellow exclamation mark beside it, indicating the device isn't working correctly]

Could you guys help me? How can I troubleshoot and solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: A hub is not a mass storage device and vice versa. USB descriptors don’t lie. How did you arrive at the conclusion that they represent the same device? In Device Manager, check the “Details” tab and look for the hardware IDs. // Not how on laptop A there is also a USB mass storage device in addition to the hub device.

Comment: Because aftet I plug/unplug, the device shows up/disappears

Comment: Your hub has a card reader. Either way, there is simply no way an incorrect detection like that could occur. // Instead, you should check you’re using a USB-C port that can do USB 3 and that can do DisplayPort. Because if it can’t do USB 3, the SuperSpeed hub won’t show up. If it cannot do DisplayPort, monitors cannot work on the hub (yes, even HDMI monitors).

Comment: I have similar problems with my Dell XPS 9560 laptop.
Devices are properly detected if connected before turning the laptop on, but not when hot-plugged.